# How to obtain a log of web search queries?

Tags: search-engine, information-retrieval

It would help if I could do a search log analysis for my research. Is it possible to use a search API (Google, Yahoo, Bing) to create a log of web search queries over a specified time span, or is it available on request?

Answer (score 1):

The only thing I know of is the old aol search logs which they released a while back. You can find it on some of the torrent sites. for news about it read [this](http://www.wired.com/politics/security/news/2006/08/71579)